# Tab is not switching but the URL of that tab is changing

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-ui-router, kendo-tabstrip

I am using tabstrip and angular UI routing to navigate those tabs. When I click on the tab, its URL changes but the tab does not switch.

I have 3 tabs. The first 2 tabs work as expected. But the last tab does not switch even though its URL changes.

Here is my code.

[image: Please click here]

Please let me know if you need further information.

Comment: Please don't use images to show code, either edit this question or delete and re-ask with the actual code in text on the page, ideally use a running snippet or plnkr to show the problem in action.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have the k-state-active class set on a particular `li`, since you're using `ui-sref` you can use `ui-sref-active="k-state-active"` on all the `li` elements instead of the `class` you have on the first, the ui-sref-active state will apply the https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/quick-reference#ui-sref-active